# Laravel 8 - ID value is an int but when inserting into table query fails because it has square brackets

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue in Laravel.

I am storing data into a table using eloquent and I am retrieving the newly created ID ($categoryId) of that record/model, when I dump out the ID it shows as an int (desired output)

However, when I try and use/store that ID in another table using an eloquent query ($newProduct->category_id = $categoryId;), it fails as it adds square brackets to the value e.g. [1].

So my question is how do I get the value without the brackets so I can use it as desired in my other eloquent query?

When I try and strip the brackets off it complains that the value is already an int, so I am a bit lost with this - Thank you for any help and guidance

Below is my code:

```
$newCategory = new Category;

$newCategory->short_desc = $category;

$newCategory->save();

$categoryId = $newCategory->id;


$newProduct = new Product;

$newProduct->name = $product_name;
$newProduct->category_id = $categoryId;

$newProduct->save();

$productId = $newProduct->id;
```

Below is the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[1]' for column 'category_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `description`, `category_id`, `container_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Razer Blade 16, AMD \" 10, [1], [2], 1, 2022-09-14 15:24:36, 2022-09-14 15:24:36))"
```

Product migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', '255')->index();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('container_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('container_id')->references('id')->on('containers');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

Category migration:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('short_desc', '255');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Comment: can u share screenshoot or file  your category and product migrations file.

Comment: @DelowarHossen Hi there I have added my migrations to the original post above - Thanks

Comment: Considering youre taking `$categoryId` to save, would `$newProduct->category_id = $newCategory->id;` be giving the same error?

Comment: @Yai Thank you, your guidance has helped me solve my issue - credited you in my answer

Comment: Do you maybe have [a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) set up in one of your models?

Comment: @Don'tPanic no mutators set up on the relevant models - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by using $newCategory->id instead of storing it in another variable - thanks for the guidance @Yai

Instead of this below:

```
$categoryId = $newCategory->id;
$newProduct->category_id = $categoryId;
```

Use this instead:

```
$newProduct->category_id = $newCategory->id;
```

For what was causing the issue when inserting into the table I have no clue.

Comment: For your reference, it has something to do with eloquent models where if the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays. I dont fully understand it so cant really explain it well. But that's a start if you want to know more

Answer (score 0):

please replace your Product migration , rollback and migrate again.

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', '255')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->integer('container_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('container_id')->references('id')->on('containers');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

        });
```

Comment: After making your changes I got this error :

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'category_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'products_category_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))`

Comment: let me share your insert full method https://prnt.sc/_ZRfRC4-zuBs

Comment: updated products migration table please replace and migrate again.

Comment: This has not worked for me, that save method is the laravel helper, there is no other code I have so I am not sure what you are asking me to include? - Another member has already solved my issue, thanks for the help

Comment: @DelowarHossen What did you change in the migration, and why do you think it will help?  Code-only answers, with no explanation, are considered low quality on SO - add an explanation so others can learn from your answer.